# PrivateMethodTester and Inheritance

Tags: scala, scalatest

So I have a class:

```
class MyParent {
    private def myMethod() = 12
}
```

And a class:

```
class MyChild extends MyParent {
}
```

In my test I want to do:

```
val c = new MyChild()

val m = PrivateMethod[MyChild]('myMethod)
assertEquals(12, c invokePrivate m())
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a private method named: myMethod
```

Any idea how to test the `method` defined in the `parent` using the `child` class ?

My use case is obviously more complex, so testing the parent method is different than testing the child method.

Thank you.

**Edit**:

One solution I found is to change `MyParent#myMethod` to `protected` and then have in the child:

```
private def wrapMyMethod() = super.myMethod()
```

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make any sense. `MyChild` simply has no method called `myMethod`, because it's a private method in the parent class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to scalatest:

The fact that `def myMethod() = 12` is `private` in the base class means it can't be used from the child classes.

The compiler won't be able to perform `new MyChild().myMethod()` nor will the `PrivateMethodTester` be able to invoke it via introspection.

---

Unrelated to the error: the type parameter of `PrivateMethod` should be `Int` (the return type of the method being tested) and not `MyChild`:

You can test it on the base class:

```
val m = PrivateMethod[Int]('myMethod)
new MyParent() invokePrivate m()
```

insteadd of:

```
val m = PrivateMethod[MyParent]('myMethod)
new MyParent() invokePrivate m()
```

---

If `def myMethod() = 12` was made `protected` then you wouldn't need to create a wrapper in the child class with the only intent to test it (as a base rule, I think unit testing should never impact the actual code), you could directly test the protected method from the base class.

To test a `protected` method, you can create a new class in your test class which extends the class containing the protected method and indeed wraps it in a public method:

```
class MyParentMock extends MyParent {
  def wrapMyMethod() = myMethod()
}

test("my_test") {
  assertEquals(12, new MyParentMock().wrapMyMethod())
}
```

Comment: oh thanks I misread http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.PrivateMethodTester !

Comment: about the question, what if `myMethod` become `protected` , would that work ?

Comment: @Wonay indeed, you can wrap the method, but you should do that from the tests with a mock of the base class. I updated the answer.

Comment: Should not `PrivateMethodTester` be able to call `protected` methods of the superclass? Right now, it is unable to find a protected method defined in the superclass when called on the subclass, but I think it should be possible. Maybe we can open a ticket or something?